# How to get specific attributes with values from an xml document using c# console?

Tags: c#

I have an xml document like below:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee Id="1" City="Seattle">
        <EmployeeName>Nancy Davolio</EmployeeName>
        <Country>USA</Country>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="2" City="Tacoma">
        <EmployeeName>Andrew Fuller</EmployeeName>
        <Country>USA</Country>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="3" City="Kirkland">
        <EmployeeName>Janet Leverling</EmployeeName>
        <Country>USA</Country>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

From this file, I like to get displayed in the console only the EmployeeName for every employee with their tags. Below is how I tried to do so but it is showing only the opening and closing tag but not the value of EmployeeName.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D://test.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        if (reader.Name == "EmployeeName")
                        {
                            Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(">");

                        }
                         break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                         if (reader.Name == "EmployeeName")
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                         }

                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        if (reader.Name == "EmployeeName")
                        {
                            Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(">");
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();



        }
```

Any help, please!

Comment: what would the output look like?

Comment: The output would like look this:<EmployeeName></EmployeeName> without the value inside the tags

Comment: for the given input 3 empty tag pair, and the xml root also, or excluded?

Comment: Excluded the root the result is three empty attributes without the value

Comment: When you step through with the debugger in the 2nd case, does it visit your node (before the `if` statement)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Actually, it reads all the file at once and displays the output.

Comment: when you are in the `case XmlNodeType.Text`, the actual Name == "EmployeeName" happened in the previous iteration

Comment: Yes, because I want to display the value of the EmployeeName node